# Export Products, 1.9.2.4 not valid data - Media.phtml

Tags: products, importexport, export

I am trying to export products using Magento, i choose export, products and returns with empty attributes list, and i click continue it says Not Valid Data.... 
i have checked log and it says:

```
2016-09-28T10:12:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: thumb_type  in //app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 44
```

i have checked that line and it says:

```
<ul id="etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>" class="<?php echo $thumb_type; ?>">
```

any help anyone ? 
regards

Comment: Anyone help with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

use this script to export all product. csv file will generate in var/importexport folder

```
  <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$data=array();
$data['entity'] = 'catalog_product';
$data['file_format'] = 'csv';
$data['form_key'] =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); 
$data['export_filter']=array();

$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
$model->setData($data);

$filename = $model->getFileName();
$content = $model->export();
file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'importexport' . DS . $filename, $content);
echo $filename;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i just get blank page as i can access the file. i named it on my magento root exportscript.php and when i run it i just get blank page PS: i changed file permission to 777 stil nothing in var/export

Comment: file is generate in importexport folder. and in screen it is always blank.

Comment: Thanks but in Var, file is not created importexport, i have also checked in App/....../importexport/export/ nothing there @jigs parmar

Comment: at the end put this :-    $filename = $model->getFileName();
    $content = $model->export();
    file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'importexport' . DS . $filename, $content);

Comment: at the end and remove last two lines

Comment: I have changed $model->export();
$model->getContentType(); TO : - $filename = $model->getFileName(); $content = $model->export(); file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'importexport' . DS . $filename, $content);
but I get Error 500 - unable to handle request

Comment: you do this in local or live?

Comment: bcs in my local it works fine

Comment: I am using Live site but not yet done marketing for it, i can still import products all fine, just this issue with Media.phtml file... :(

Comment: just see. i update script. create importexport folder under var folder and run this script

Comment: Really thanks for help, i did update the script to the latest one, and i did create folder importexport.php in root magento and run it through browser result is White blank page and no csv file created in Var/importexport :(

Comment: some other extension affact export import thats why this happens try this in local. i use this code in my extension its work fine